# GIF Drawing dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, gif

I have made a video game like Space Invaders(C# Winforms), and I need to add an explosion gif whenever a missile comes into contact with an enemy. Basically, I need a gif to go through one animation cycle and disappear. Is there any easy-ish way to go about this? My hit detection code occurs on timer tick, and looks something like this:

```
if (ShotList[i].LocationX + 20 >     MediumEnemyWave[k].LocationX && ShotList[i].LocationX + 20 < MediumEnemyWave[k].LocationX + 80 && ShotList[i].LocationY - 25 <= MediumEnemyWave[k].LocationY && MediumEnemyWave[k].IsDestroyed == false)
                {
                    lbloutput.Text = "conf hit MED";
                    ShotList[i].IsActive = false;
//INSERT PLAY EXPLOSION ANIMATION ONCE CODE HERE
                    MediumEnemyWave[k].Health--;
                }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @MickyD My bad, Winforms c#

Comment: I think you will first have to analyze the gif and extract all the frames into an image array or an imagelist. then you can draw them succesively..